# MLB Mound Visits: initiating a visit when MVR = 0

Tags: rules, mlb

What will happen in the event that a manager or coaching staff member, (or player) attempts to approach the mound when there are no Mound Visits Remaining?  Will the initiating visitor be ejected?

EDIT: According to the current MLB Rule Book, it does not appear to be explicitly stated.  However, it seems that it would follow the protocol for when a manager visits his pitcher twice in the same inning without removing him: the manager is ejected; the current pitcher must face the current batter; then the pitcher must be removed from the game.

Answer (score 1):

A catcher may ask the home-plate umpire for a brief visit if he is crossed up on a pitch and the team is out of mound visits.

Read more here: http://www.kansascity.com/sports/mlb/kansas-city-royals/article200911059.html#storylink=cpy

The umpire likely won't call time out if a catcher requests a mound visit, or a manager requests a mound visit, and any rules that require the catcher to take his position and the batter to take his position will be imposed. Not sure if it is in the rules, but likely the umpire will begin calling balls even if the pitcher is not throwing. So there would be no advantage for trying to violate the rules.

Comment: Good article.  This new rule seems to have lost any relevance.  It's hardly been in headlines or highlights.